# Solutions to $[x^2]+2[x]=3x\text{ where } 0\le x\le 2$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, functions

> Find all solutions to $$[x^2]+2[x]=3x\text{ where } 0\le x\le 2$$
>   and $[x]=\lfloor x\rfloor$

$$$$
I managed to simplify this to $[x^2]-[x]=3\{x\}$. Thus, $$[x^2]-[x]=\{0,1,2\}$$ However I got stuck here and was unable to proceed further. Somehow I have a feeling that there's a much neater approach than what I've taken.$$$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: If $\left[\cdots\right]$ means *floor function*, the usual notation is $\left\lfloor\cdots\right\rfloor$ which is the $\LaTeX$ $\verb!\left\lfloor yourText \right\rfloor!$

Comment: @FelixMarin I've just edited the question.

Comment: In the last 24 hours you have posted quite a few questions all on the same theme: solve completely unmotivated equations involving floor functions and fractional parts of numbers. Could you *please* explain where in the world all these equations are coming from and why you are interested in such equations?

Comment: You did everything , now you just need to do case analysis for every set

Comment: For example, in this post the equation is $[x^2] + 2[x] = 3x$. I can't help thinking: what's the point? I do not see how such equations would come up to solve a problem and you are giving us no reason to see why the solutions would be useful.

Comment: @KCd Sir actually the last few days I had been revising Functions - I have an exam in a month which would test several chapters including Functions, and I came across a Worksheet which had about 31 questions solely on the Greatest Integer and Fractional Part Functions. Hence I thought of solving the worksheet for practice, and thus have been asking for help whenever I've been unable to solve the questions.

Comment: The left side is an integer. So $3x$ is an integer. Thus the only candidates are $x=0,1/3,2/3,1,4/3,5/3,2$. Check by computing which ones work.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks Sir!

Comment: @user342209: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write
$$x={k\over3}\qquad(0\leq k\leq 6)$$
with integer $k$. The condition then is
$$\left\lfloor{k^2\over 9}\right\rfloor+2\left\lfloor{k\over 3}\right\rfloor=k\ .$$
Within the given range only $k=0$ and $k=3$ do qualify, so that we obtain the two solutions $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If  $0\leq x<1$, $LHD=0$.

$1\leq x<\sqrt2$, $LHD=3$

$\sqrt2\leq x<\sqrt3,LHD=4$

$\sqrt3\leq x<2,LHD=5$

So x is a rational number by feature of equation, $x=0,1,2$